# cherrypy single page app with react.js (no error + blank page)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cherrypy

I am a complete noob to cherrypy and worked through a set of tutorials, but one has me stumped.

Tutorial:
https://docs.cherrypy.dev/en/latest/tutorials.html?highlight=react#tutorial-10-make-it-a-modern-single-page-application-with-react-js

I get a blank page. There is no error:

> 127.0.0.1 - - [10/Apr/2016:09:17:38] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 518 "" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0"
> 127.0.0.1 - - [10/Apr/2016:09:17:38] "GET /static/js/gen.js HTTP/1.1" 200 4186 "http://0.0.0.0:8084/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0"
> 127.0.0.1 - - [10/Apr/2016:09:17:38] "GET /static/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 45 "http://0.0.0.0:8084/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0"
> 127.0.0.1 - - [10/Apr/2016:09:17:38] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 1406 "" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0"

file set (code copied from above tutorial and not altered):

```
workspace/cherrypy/index.html
workspace/cherrypy/public/css/style.css
workspace/cherrypy/public/js/gen.js
```

If I view the source for the page in browser, it looks just like the html ... nothing extra when I expected input boxes to generate a random number.

```
<body>
      <div id="generator"></div>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/gen.js"></script>
</body>
```

Have I missed a simple step? I have reread the material a couple of times and cannot figure it out.

Comment: Clarifying for those who are looking at the original code...  I did change port value in the tutorials code set which makes no difference because I can view the outcome on port 8084.

Comment: Looking at this further, because I am determined to get it.   Tried using http://127.0.0.1:8084/generator and I still get a blank page  '127.0.0.1 - - [13/Apr/2016:10:14:12] "GET /generator HTTP/1.1" 200 - "" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0"'